# Suppressing nightwatchjs warnings in terminal output

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatchjs to run my test suite, and I would like to remove the warning messages being outputted to my terminal display.

At the moment, I'm getting loads of these (admittedly genuine) warning messages whilst my scripts are running and it's making the reading of the results harder and harder.

As an example;

[image]

Yes they are valid messages, but it's not often possible for me to uniquely pick out each individual element and I'm not interested in them for my output.

So, I'd like to know how I can stop them from being reported in my terminal.

Below is what I've tried so far in my ***nightwatch.conf.js*** config file;

```
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                javascriptEnabled : true,
                acceptSslCerts: true,
                acceptInscureCerts: true,
                chromeOptions : {
                    args: [
                        '--ignore-certificate-errors',
                        '--allow-running-insecure-content',
                        '--disable-web-security',
                        '--disable-infobars',
                        '--disable-popup-blocking',
                        '--disable-notifications',
                        '--log-level=3'],
                    prefs: {
                        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.popups' : 1,
                        'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications' : 1
                    },
                },
            },
        },

but it's still displaying the warnings.

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Many thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `detailed_output` property to false in the configuration file. This should stop these details from printing in the console.

You can find a sample config file [here](https://github.com/spnraju/demo-nightwatchjs-tests/blob/master/nightwatch.conf.js#L15).

You can find relevant details available under `Output Settings` section of official docs [here](https://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted/configuration/).

Update 1: This looks like a combo of properties which controls this and the below combo works for me.

```
  live_output: false,
  silent: true,
  output: true,
  detailed_output: false,
  disable_error_log: false,
```

Comment: Ah no, this has already been disabled. Sorry, I should have posted my setup 'fully':  `module.exports = {
 globals_path: 'config/globals.js',
   page_objects_path: 'config/page_objects',
 custom_commands_path: 'config/commands',
 detailed_output: false,
 output: true,
 disable_error_log: true,
 test_workers: false,
 src_folders: [
  'tests/'
 ],`

Comment: the configuration I have in the link works fine for me. I am updating my answer with more props

Comment: Hmm, strange @Raju as my config is now;   `
module.exports = {
 globals_path: 'config/globals.js',
   page_objects_path: 'config/page_objects',
 custom_commands_path: 'config/commands',
 detailed_output: false,
 output: true,
 silent: true,
 live_output: false,
 disable_error_log: false,
 test_workers: false,
 src_folders: [
  'tests/'
 ],` and yet I still get the warnings displayed.

Comment: which version of nightwatch are you on? do you have any sample repo where i can reproduce this?

Comment: I'm using nightwatch v6.4.1. This happens on all tests, it's just the "Warn:...." message I'd like to get rid of. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Darren, Would you mind sharing link to this library? I could not find your version here. https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/releases